# updating PATH to work for every current working dir

Tags: bash, shell, process, path

Say I have this defined for PATH

```
export PATH="./node_modules/.bin:${PATH}"
```

does that mean that any process that uses PATH, will have a reference to `node_modules/.bin` from the current working dir?

Comment: That depends on where the PATH is being set and what shell the process is using.

Comment: If the PATH is being set previously, in a parent shell.

Answer (score 2):

If the `export PATH … …` call was executed by a parent shell of the shell where the present command is called and that PATH has not been modified by some intermediary shell, then:

```
Yes
```

All child commands will search for executables (first) inside `./node_modules/.bin` of any `pwd`. A pretty serious and clear security hole, Don't do it.